# Replacing recursion with a while loop

Tags: c, loops, recursion, assembly, tail-recursion

For performance reasons, are recursions ever replaced with `while` loops? I know the code looks much uglier, but let's take the following example:

```
void print_countdown(long long n) {
    if (n!=0) {
        printf("Placeholder for a function\n");
        print_countdown(n-1);
    } else 
        printf("Done!\n");
}
```

If the number is 1 million, then this will have an overhead of:

- 1 million copies of the `n` var (saved from rdi, put back in rdi for the recursive call, if the recursive work includes a function call, otherwise it can stay in rdi.)
- `call func`
- `push rbp ... pop` function prologue or something else for stack alignment, depending on optimization level and compiler choices.

In other words, while the code is readable, for anything like > 1000 loops, this seems to be better rewritten to something like:

```
void print_countdown(long long n) {
    while (n < MAX_LOOPS) {
        if (n!=0) {
            printf("Placeholder for a function\n");
            n = n-1;     
        } else
            printf("Done!");
    }
    
}
```

The [assembly code (Godbolt)](https://godbolt.org/z/jqG3Ta) also looks much, much simpler in the `while` format -- ~20 lines vs ~40 lines.

Is it common to do this kind of loop-rewriting, and are there ever times in a recursive function call where it cannot be re-written to a `loop` ?

Comment: C++ compilers would (usually) do tail recursion optimisation if compiled with -O3 flag

Comment: @tf3 could you please explain that a bit, what is tail optimization?

Comment: Compile with `-O3` and find out.  (But basically, replacing call foo / ret with jmp foo is standard tailcall optimization.  In a recursive function, this creates a loop that can be optimized further.)

Comment: Tail recursion optimisation is an optimisation where the compiler replaces recursion with iteration, if it identifies that the underlying process is in fact iterative ie, uses constant amount of resources and if its 'state' information at any time is captured by a constant number of variables. A recursive process would consume resources depending upon the number of calls made to the (recursively called) function, unlike the iterative process. A function can be called in a recursive manner but it can still be an iterative process, in which case, the compiler can make this optimisation.

Comment: @tf3 you can see in this example though that TCO did not happen, it's kind of funny to post the assertion that it will happen under a counter example

Comment: @PeterCordes yes the link to Compiler Explorer already has `-O3` and it doesn't do anything I don't think.

Comment: @tf3, PeterCordes, I thought that this optimization was also made with `-O1` or `-O2`, is `-O3` required for tail recursion? (i.e. on `gcc`)?

Comment: @harold: But it *does* happen here if you copy the actual code from the code block into Godbolt, instead of following the OP's link to different code.  https://godbolt.org/z/j6cra4.  Shows that the empty tail-recursion loop gets optimized away, leaving just the `movl  $.LC0, %edi` / `jmp puts` base case with no looping or recursion left after optimization.  And no push rbp in sight anywhere even in the OP's Godbolt link.  Yes it turns out putting a `printf` into the recursion loop defeats GCC for some reason and it still recurses.

Comment: @DavidRanieri: No, `-O3` is not required, I only said that to chime in with tf3's comment.  (I didn't notice the Godbolt link right away because links are less visible on code formatting, which the link text used for no reason.)

Comment: @DavidRanieri i am not too experienced, but if the manual says so then it can be done.

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you for the question edits, you make my questions seem much smarter than they actually are!

Comment: Sometimes fixing the question to ask the interesting thing avoids making answers spend time dealing with misconceptions in the question, letting the answer be better.  Also better for future readers to not be misled in the first place by some parts of the premise / setup in the question.  So yeah, turning questions into something I think it would be useful to have answered is not just for your benefit :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep.

Proof: https://godbolt.org/z/EqbnfY

This code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_countdown(long long n) {
    if (n!=0) {
        // do_something
        print_countdown(n-1);
    } else 
        printf("Done!\n");
}
```

Generates this assembly with the x86-64 Clang compiler and `-O2` optimizations (the compiler even generates the comments too!)

```
print_countdown(long long):                   # @print_countdown(long long)
        mov     edi, offset .Lstr
        jmp     puts                            # TAILCALL
.Lstr:
        .asciz  "Done!"
```

Other compilers generate similar results.

Comment: For some reason, having a non-inline function call like `printf` as the `// do_something` defeats GCC, which instead unrolls by 4 but keeps the recursion instead of a loop.  Only recursing every 4 `puts` calls is better than every 1, but still much worse than a loop.  Of course, with recursive work that *can* inline, GCC does much better.

Comment: @PeterCordes - did you compile with optimizations?  Look here: https://godbolt.org/z/PEzch7

Comment: @selbie. Peter refers to https://godbolt.org/z/baofGc

Comment: I'm talking about the Godbolt link in the question, https://godbolt.org/z/jqG3Ta - using the updated code block, compiled by GCC10.2 -O3.  @DavidRanieri's link (https://godbolt.org/z/baofGc) is that code with clang, which *does* optimize away the recursion into a loop as you say.  There's no reason GCC can't, it's just a missed optimization.

Comment: Note that the asm in your question has not only optimized away the recursion, it's also optimized away the resulting empty loop (of `--n` down to 0), leaving just one tailcall of puts.  (GCC does that, too, when the recursive loop is empty)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, tail call elimination is a common optimization. If you haven't seen it yet, check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call, which talks about this topic in detail.

> The GCC, LLVM/Clang, and Intel compiler suites perform tail call optimization for C and other languages at higher optimization levels or when the `-foptimize-sibling-calls` option is passed. Though the given language syntax may not explicitly support it, the compiler can make this optimization whenever it can determine that the return types for the caller and callee are equivalent, and that the argument types passed to both function are either the same, or require the same amount of total storage space on the call stack.

The Wiki page also has an assembly example of how an optimizer might revise a recursive routine to a loop.